# menu driver program in prolog with multiple input?

Tags: prolog

I am designing a menu driven prolog code to find distance.

My code looks like this

```
road(arad, zerind, 75).
road(arad, sibiu, 140).
road(arad, timisoara, 118).

depth_first([[Goal|Path]|_],Goal,[Goal|Path],0).
depth_first([Path|Queue],Goal,FinalPath,N) :-
    extend(Path,NewPaths), 
    append(NewPaths,Queue,NewQueue),
    depth_first(NewQueue,Goal,FinalPath,M),
    N is M+1.

extend([Node|Path],NewPaths) :-
    findall([NewNode,Node|Path],
            (road(Node,NewNode,_), 
            \+ member(NewNode,Path)), % for avoiding loops
            NewPaths).

run:-
    write('Enter the ORIGIN City: '),read(S),
    write('Enter the Destination City: '),read(D),
    write('Type of search: '),nl,
    write('1. depth_first search 2. exit'),nl,
    write('Enter your option:'),nl,
    read(X),choice(X).
    choice(X):-X=:=1, 
    depth_first([[S]],D,P,C), writeln([P]).
```

Everytime I run my code the console just prints true and exits. I know I am doing some noob mistake but I can't figure from last hour.

and if I run it in console as

```
depth_first([[arad]],zerind,P,C)
```

it runs and prints.

UPDATE:
"depth_first([[S]],D,P,C), writeln([P])" This just print numbers at the place of text.

Comment: If your Prolog gave you warnings about singleton variables, understand and fix those. Search StackOverflow for lots of answers about why this is important. If your Prolog did not give you warnings about singleton variables, use a better Prolog.

Answer (score -2):

```
run:-
    write('Enter the ORIGIN City: '),read(S),
    write('Enter the Destination City: '),read(D),
    write('Type of search: '),nl,
    write('1. depth_first search 2. exit'),nl,
    write('Enter your option:'),nl,
    read(X),choice(X).
```

At this point, the run predicate definition stops (with the full stop).
And the choice predicate begins:

```
   choice(X):-X=:=1, 
        depth_first([[S]],D,P,C), writeln([P]).
```

So run/0 succeeds and doesn't do anything. So there is your bug. Does this help you ?

Comment: No it just prints a number [[_12372]] , I want it to print the text.

Comment: Is their any other way to print ?

Comment: I've simply pointed out your mistake to help you.  If you don't understand something, post a new question. I have not done your homework.